# What spectroscopic methods are there?

Tags: observational-astronomy, spectroscopy

It was said in a comment on this site that there are different ways spectroscopy can be achieved. I am therefore asking: What methods are available when doing spectroscopy on the composition of planets in our solar system? If you have valuable information to share, please explain the workings of each of these. Didn't find what I was looking for on the net.

Comment: Amateurs don’t have the same opportunities that professional astronomers have, but an amateur can acquire spectra of Uranus, as shown here: https://www.astrobin.com/k9ojv7/.

Comment: What were you looking for, where did you search for what?

Comment: @planetmaker. I shall be perfectly honest with you. I am struggling with this whole subject. Have perused the net and watched a few YouTube films on the subject. Can you recommend something? A YouTube film, or a book? Like; Spectroscopy  for Dummies.

Comment: According to ["Planetary Spectroscopy"](https://doi.org/10.1093/acrefore/9780190647926.013.134) in the Oxford Research Encyclopedia of Planetary Science, there are "twelve types of spectroscopy frequently used in planetary explorations", ranging from gamma rays (keV) to far infrared (µm).  This is more than can be explained in an Astronomy Stack Exchange answer. You might get better responses if your question was more specific.